# Set values in a multi-level pandas data frame python

Tags: python, pandas

I have been working with multi-level DataFrames pretty recently, and I have found that they can significantly reduce computation time for large data sets. For example, consider the simple data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, 111, 0], [2, 222, 0], [1, 111, 0],
        [2, 222, 1], [1, 111, 1], [2, 222, 2]
    ], columns=["ID", "A", "B"], index=[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
)
df.head(6)

    ID   A    B
1   1   111   0
1   2   222   0
2   1   111   0
2   2   222   1
3   1   111   1
3   2   222   2
```

which can be pivoted by ID to create a multi-level data frame:

```
pivot_df = df.pivot(columns="ID")
pivot_df.head()

     A        B
ID   1   2    1   2
1   111 222   0   0
2   111 222   0   1
3   111 222   1   2
```

The great thing about having my data in this format is that I can perform "vector" operations across all IDs simply by referencing the level 0 columns:

```
pivot_df["A"] * (1 + pivot_df["B"])**2

ID  1   2
1   111 222
2   111 888
3   444 999
```

These operations are really helpful for me! In real life, my computations are much more complex and need to be performed for > 1000 IDs. A common DataFrame size that I work with contains 10 columns (at level 0) with 1000 IDs (at level 1) with 350 rows.

I am interested in figuring out to do two things: update values for a particular field in this pivoted DataFrame; create a new column for this DataFrame. Something like

```
pivot_df["A"] = pivot_df["A"] * (1 + pivot_df["B"])**2
```

or

```
pivot_df["C"] = pivot_df["A"] * (1 + pivot_df["B"])**2
```

I do not get any errors when I perform either of these, but the DataFrame remains unchanged. I have also tried using .loc and .iloc, but I am having no success.

I think that the problem is maintaining the multi-level structure of the computed DataFrames, but I am pretty new to using multi-level DataFrames and not sure how to solve this problem efficiently. I have a clumsy workaround that is not efficient (create a dictionary of computed DataFrames and then merge them all together...

```
df_dict = OrderedDict()
df_dict["A"] = pivot_df["A"]
df_dict["B"] = pivot_df["B"]
df_dict["C"] = pivot_df["A"] * (1 + pivot_df["B"])**2

dfs = [val.T.set_index(np.repeat(key, val.shape[1]), append=True).T for key, val in df_dict.iteritems()]
final_df = reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, left_index=True, right_index=True), dfs)
final_df.columns = final_df.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
```

or similarly,

```
df_dict = OrderedDict()
df_dict["A"] = pivot_df["A"] * (1 + pivot_df["B"])**2
df_dict["B"] = pivot_df["B"]

dfs = [val.T.set_index(np.repeat(key, val.shape[1]), append=True).T for key, val in df_dict.iteritems()]
final_df = reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, left_index=True, right_index=True), dfs)
final_df.columns = final_df.columns.swaplevel(0, 1)
```

This is not necessarily clunky (I was kind of proud of the workaround), but this is certainly not efficient or computationally optimized. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Your code does not generate the dataframe you are showing.

Comment: Whoops, I must have copied the wrong code from my Jupyter Notebook.. I should have replaced `df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 111, 0], [2, 222, 0], [1, 111, 0], [2, 222, 1], 
                   [1, 111, 1], [2, 222, 2]], columns=["ID", "A", "B"], 
                   index=[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])`

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**
*Don't pivot first!*
You stated that it was convenient to pivot because you could perform vector calculations in the new pivoted form.  This is a mis-representation because you could have easily performed those calculations prior to the pivot.

```
df['C'] = df["A"] * (1 + df["B"]) ** 2
df.pivot(columns='ID')

      A       B       C      
ID    1    2  1  2    1     2
1   111  222  0  0  111   222
2   111  222  0  1  111   888
3   111  222  1  2  444  1998
```

Or in a piped one-liner if you prefer

```
df.assign(C=df.A * (1 + df.B) ** 2).pivot(columns='ID')

      A       B       C      
ID    1    2  1  2    1     2
1   111  222  0  0  111   222
2   111  222  0  1  111   888
3   111  222  1  2  444  1998
```

---

**Option 2**
*`pd.concat`*
But to answer your question...

```
pdf = df.pivot(columns='ID')
pd.concat([
        pdf.A, pdf.B, pdf.A * (1 + pdf.B) ** 2
    ], axis=1, keys=['A', 'B', 'C'])

      A       B       C      
ID    1    2  1  2    1     2
1   111  222  0  0  111   222
2   111  222  0  1  111   888
3   111  222  1  2  444  1998
```

---

**Option 3**
*more `pd.concat`*
Add another level to columns prior to concat

```
pdf = df.pivot(columns='ID')
c = pdf.A * (1 + pdf.B) ** 2
c.columns = [['C'] * len(c.columns), c.columns]

pd.concat([pdf, c], axis=1)

      A       B       C      
ID    1    2  1  2    1     2
1   111  222  0  0  111   222
2   111  222  0  1  111   888
3   111  222  1  2  444  1998
```

Comment: As part of my process I need to perform a `cumsum()` and a `cumprod()` by ID at different points in my computation process, so that is another reason that I need to pivot instead of performing the calculations directly. I perform some custom auto-regressive calculations by lD. The PD concat might be more efficient, but what about directly changing the values of A?

Comment: @RMatt that makes sense.  Options 2 and 3 should help you take care of it then.